# Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}|f(x)|^{f(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be differentiable on $(a,b)$ and let $c\in(a,b)$. Suppose that $f$ and $f'$ are nonzero on a deleted neighborhood of $c$, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=0$. Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}|f(x)|^{f(x)}$

Since this question is under topic L'Hospital's Rule, so what I have try is try to change the question into the form 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow c}|f(x)|^{f(x)}=\exp \lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{\ln|f(x)|}{1/f(x)}$$

And since it is indeterminate form, I want to apply L'Hospital's Rule but how to differentiate $|f(x)|$?

Comment: Since $f,f'$ are nonzero on a deleted neighbourhood of $c$, you have either $f(x)>0$ or $f(x)<0$ for $x>c$. Same goes for $x<c$. Thus you could look at left- and right-sided limits.

Comment: @Hirshy so do i need to use L'Hospital's Rule?

Comment: Why don't you just change variables: $y=f(x)$, so that you find $\lim_{y \to 0} |y|^y$? This is legitimate, since $f(x) \neq 0$ in a neighborhood of $c$.

Comment: Also, why do you need the assumption that $f$ is differentiable? (except maybe to be sure you can use l'Hopital, but that is not necessary for the limit itself)

Comment: Not sure why you wrote $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=0.$ Since $f$ is continuous, you could just say $f(c)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

The function $g(z)=z^z$ is extended by continuity at $z=0$ and $g(0)=1$. By given conditions $f$ is increasing or decreasing in an suitable neighborhood of $x=c$. Choose $f$ increasing (same reasoning if $f$ is assumed decreasing) in such a neighborhood.

We have then $|f(x)|= -f(x)$ if $x<c$ and $|f(x)|=f(x)$ if $x>c$. Therefore $|f(x)|^{f(x)}$ becomes of the form $\frac{1}{Z^Z}$ when $x<c$ and of the form $Z^Z$ when $x>c$. Consequently,taking into account the function g above, the ask limit is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume limit $f'$ not zero then as commented we can assume $f>0$. We have come down to evaluate:

$$\frac{\ln{f}}{1/f}= \frac{-\infty}{\infty}$$

Applying the rule we get after cancelling $f'$ that the limit of $\frac{\ln{f}}{1/f}$ is $0$ and so the limit is $1$.